# How do I remove an old windows partition that is still needed?

Tags: windows, partitioning

My primary drive has two partitions, an old XP partition and a newer 7 partition, in that order. I want to remove the XP partition but I believe the bios relies on the info in the XP to boot properly into the 7 one. How can I most easily axe the first partition without hosing up the second and keep everything working?

My two goals for this are to not having to re-run setup and exapnd the drive space for my 7 install.

Comment: Not sure if you can. I bet you can manually remove the folders you don't need (be careful not to remove the ones the bootloader created), then shrink the partition and move everything over, but in order to do that you will need partitioning software.

Comment: Which OS was installed First?

Comment: XP was installed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly complex, and I'm not sure of your skill level so I'm not going to go into too much detail.

If you're unsure of any of these steps then definitely seek help on the specific issue you face. If you're unsure about all of it then seek professional assistance, as this is something that could go horribly wrong if you don't know what you're doing.

But on a high level I recommend:

1. Back up the entire disk *(Important!)* **EDIT:** This step cannot be overemphasized, and unless you really know what you are doing, this means doing a **full drive backup/clone**, not just backing up your files.  The following process is definitely risky and you have a very real chance of trashing your data. Drive cloning means that worst-case you take out the old drive and plug in the backup drive and you're no worse off than before. I recommend [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to clone to a same-size or larger drive.
2. *Test that the backup works by removing your old drive and booting from the backup drive*.
3. Download the [Windows ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7) and burn it to DVD or make a bootable USB drive using [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) or [this](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)
4. Test that the bootable DVD/USB works
5. Get yourself a Linux boot disk / USB stick, my personal favourite is [System Rescue CD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/), and boot into this.
6. Open [GParted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual) then:

   - Remove the XP Partition
   - Move the Windows 7 partition to the start of the disk, then resize it as required
   - Commit the changes to update the partition table and move the data (this could take a very long time, be patient)
7. Boot using the Windows 7 DVD/USB then try a [bootloader repair](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-manually-troubleshoot-and-repair-windows-7-bootloader)

Good luck

Comment: This is a very risky procedure. If it fails and the backup requires windows, the backup becomes unavailable too. So I would change step 1: backup using something that does not require windows to restore.

Comment: @LPChip I agree it is risky, hence my hesitation in getting too involved in the steps.  I agree that step 1 is probably glossed over more than it should have been, this is a critical step and I didn't mean "back up your files", I meant "image your disk to a secondary drive so you can drop the drive straight in should things go awry".  I'll clarify - thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still miss one thing: The backup should be restored through other means than the current windows install. So it should be able to create recovery media, and this should be tested before attempting this. I've once made the mistake to create a backup and when things went wrong, I had a backup, but I couldn't restore it because I had no way anymore. Made me take hours of time to reinstall windows and the backup software only to restore a backup. Nowadays I test that I have working recovery media if I do something this drastic.

Comment: @LPChip that's why I suggested doing a disk clone.  You don't need any OS of software tools to do the restore, you just swap the physical disks.  And testing the backup is vital, I outlined that in the new step 2 :)

Comment: Right.... You do realize that most people do not have a spare disk laying around, that they're willing to completely wipe in order to do this?

Comment: If you have a (I'm assuming full) drive that you need to back up before making major alterations, then yes, you're going to need another spare drive at least that big to back it all up regardless of the method you use, unless you want to start dealing with compressed backups.  I didn't want to go there.  Yes, using my method you will have to sacrifice the spare drive even if it isn't empty but has enough space - but like I said at the very start, this isn't for beginners and I'm just giving some pointers as to what I've done in the past.  If you have a better answer feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the bios relies on the info in the XP to boot properly into the 7 one.

Nope.  The BIOS's job is to determine what disk is bootable, and then run code in the boot loader.  The boot loader's main job is to figure out what partition has code that needs to run, and run it.  (If the boot loader gives you choices, it may be called a boot manager.)  Then the code in the partition runs.

Hopefully things are simple: the code in the partition runs the operating system.  It is possible for things to be more complex: code in the partition could act like a boot manager/loader, and run code from somewhere else.

If you screw up the boot process, it can be restored.  Restoring the boot process can be a bit unpleasant, as this often involves booting from something other than your hard drive, and possibly using disk-specializing tools that might not have the easier user interfaces.  However, restoring the boot process (if the operating systems are left in tact) is really a fairly small amount of data to be written (as in, a small number of clusters... maybe hundreds of kilobytes, or maybe even so few kilobytes that you can count them with your fingers).